# MySQL Database like bank accounts daily transactions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Database with two tables: `users` and `payments`

The `users` table is populated with

```
name
address
age
plan
```

The `payment` table is populated with

```
name, address
age, plan
paidamount, transactionid
paiddate, receivedby
updatedby, authorisedby
```

Users table contains about 1000 rows; they are fixed, and they regularly pay in a certain amount for savings.

I need to get user data from the users table into a webpage with a form, 
while inserting their payment information into it, and posting the entire data to the payment table where I used the code below, but I can't post the user table data with this form.

```
INSERT INTO Payments
    (ampaid, rcamo, userchar, totamo) VALUES 
    ('@ampaid', '@rcamo', '@userchar', '@totamo'),
    ('$_POST[ampaid]','$_POST[rcamo]','$_POST[userchar]','$_POST[totamo]');
 (SELECT name, ero, srno, address FROM Users WHERE srno='@srno'));
```

But I am not able to fetch from the `users` table when I update `payments`

Comment: we can not write complete logic for you. Just provide what you have tried

Comment: why are you writing selet statement in insert query? (any specific reason?). The query   "INSERT INTO payment (ampaid, rcamo, userchar, totamo) VALUES ('@ampaid', '@rcamo', '@userchar', '@totamo');" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Firstly

Never include `$_POST` values in your queries [for this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Parameterize or prepare them, using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). (Also, that syntax is invalid for including in a string, and hence you are trying to add the literal string `'$_POST[var]'` to an `INT` field)

Your real issue here is that you are not using MySQL as it should be used (an **RDBMS**. See the next section:

---

### Relationships

Look up [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). They link your tables together, and hence you should **never be inserting the contents of a table into another on every update**. You should insert the ID of the row in the user's table to do this, and then use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

---

### The Actual Insertion

To insert multiple values at once, use the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO
    `table` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES
    (:val1, :val2), (:val3, :val4)
```

and create this array:

```
Array(
    ":val1" => $val1,
    ":val2" => $val2, // etc.
);
```

This is using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Look it up, learn to love it, etc. There are plenty of resources on StackOverflow with examples and the occasional pitfall.

### Getting Started

```
$params = array(
    ":ampaid" => $_POST["ampaid"], // tip: use quotes for array keys...
    ":rcamo" => $_POST["rcamo"], 
    ":userchar" => $_POST["userchar"],
    ":totamo" => $_POST["totamo"]
);

$db = new PDO($connection_info, $user, $pass); // from a config file
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // throw errors

$sql = "INSERT INTO `payment` (`ampaid`, `rcamo`, `userchar`, `totamo`) " .
       "VALUES (:ampaid, :rcamo, :userchar, :totamo)";

$prepare = $db->prepare($sql); // prepare query
$prepare->execute($params); // execute query using bound parameters
```

I'll leave the error handling up to you as homework. (tip: `try-catch`)

You cannot use the result of a `SELECT` query to populate an `INSERT` query in the same call (correct me if i'm wrong, but it's still a terrible idea).

---

### Lastly

**Never** insert *unsanitized* or *unprepared* user input. If this is a real banking application (which I kind of doubt... hopefully), I'd be extremely scared to trust my money with this. In fact, I'd much rather make money through the inevitable lawsuits, so be careful and ***sanitize absolutely any user input you ever receive, period***.

Answer (score -2):

what i get from above discussion is @user2226832 want to insert multiple values in table,
So you can do like this-

```
INSERT INTO payment 
    (ampaid, rcamo, userchar, totamo) VALUES 
    ('@ampaid', '@rcamo', '@userchar', '@totamo'),
    ('$_POST[ampaid]','$_POST[rcamo]','$_POST[userchar]','$_POST[totamo]');
```

Note: Code is not tested, but syntax is correct just take care of your single quotes.

Comment: the syntax is not correct. 1) injection risks, 2) purposefully creating injection risks doesnt work like that (you double quote and use {}, and quote the array values) 3) at least tell him that $_POST[var] isnt even valid for string interpolation and that his error is trying to stick a string in an int field